# How to show that a map without fix point from annular region to annular region is homotopic to antipodal map

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

$\Omega=\{x\in R^3: 1\le||x||\le2\}$

If $L:\Omega\rightarrow \Omega $ is continuous and without fix point , how to show $L$ is homotopic with antipodal map $x\rightarrow -x$?

Comment: @MichaelHarrison  I try to make homotopy $H(x,t)=\frac{tL(x)+(1-t)(-x)}{||tL(x)+(1-t)(-x)||}$, but when $f(x)=\lambda x $ at some $x$, it is not continuous.

Comment: You are right.  I was thinking of $\Omega = S^2$, in which case your answer works.

Comment: @MichaelHarrison  But when it is annular region, I don't know how to deal it .

Comment: What about  $L(r,\theta)=(r,\theta+1)$, is this homotopicl with the antipodal map? Wouldn't that mean antipodal map is homotopic with the identity?

Comment: I'm afraid some condition is missing. $L(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\lVert x\rVert}}\cdot x$ is continuous without fixed point, but is homotopic to the identity (which has degree $1$) and hence not homotopic to the antipodal map (which has degree $-1$).

Comment: @MarcoDisce Do you mean rotation? Rotation of $S^2$ has fix point . You can read this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675676/fix-point-of-ls2-rightarrow-s2

Comment: @lanse2pty sorry I read "annular region" and considered the two dimensional case

Comment: @DanielFischer  Yes ,the $\Omega$ should be close domain. I have edit it .Thanks.

Comment: Thinking about your space as $S^2\times I$, I think -- for the most part -- the usual proof of this fact for $S^2$ carries over to your case.  The only hiccup is if there's a point whose spherical component is fixed: $L(x,t) = (x,s)$ with $t\neq s$.  I'm inclined to believe this implies there's a fixed point (via Brouwer's theorem), but I don't have all the details.

Comment: @SteveD  I thought same with you, but I can't prove too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The homology of $\Omega$ is $H_0(\Omega,\Bbb{Q})=H_2(\Omega,\Bbb{Q})=\Bbb{Q}$ and $H_i(\Omega,\Bbb{Q})=0$ if $i\ne 0,2$.

The [Lefschetz formula](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lefschetz_formula) tells you that a map f without fixpoints necessarily 
$0=Tr(H_0(f))+Tr(H_2(f)=H_0(f)+H_2(f)$. But $H_0(f)=H_0(id)=1$ for all $f$,
 hence in our case $H_2(f)=-1=H_2(-id)$. By the [rational 
Hurewicz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem) and the naturality of the Hurewicz map this implies that $\pi_2(f)=\pi_2(-id)$, hence $f$ is homotopic to $-id$.